# Mulitple condition filter on row and apply color React Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using react-table to show data. In that I want to use multiple condition on table row and color as below:

```
const WORK_ORDER_COLUMNS = [{
    Header: 'ID',
    accessor: 'id',
    width: 50
  }, {
    Header: 'Product',
    accessor: 'product',
    width: 150
  } , {
    id: 'Stage Progress',
    Header: 'Stage Progress',
    accessor: (data : any) => { 

      return (data.stage_due_date !== null 
            ?(data.stage_due_date > moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/yyyy') ? "On time"
            :data.stage_due_date < moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/yyyy') ? "Over Due" 
            :data.stage_due_date = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/yyyy') ? "Due Today"
            :data.stage_due_date ):
       "Not Access")
    
    }
]
```

As I want to apply conditions on `stage_due_date` column. Also I want to highlight them with different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making result data in `<div>` we can add CSS into it.

```
accessor: (data : any) => { 

      return (data.stage_due_date !== null 
            ?(data.stage_due_date > moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/yyyy') ? <div className="OnTime">On Time </div>
            :data.stage_due_date < moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/yyyy') ? <div className="Overdue">Over Due </div> 
            :data.stage_due_date = moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/yyyy') ? <div className="DueToday">Due Today </div>
            :data.stage_due_date ):
       "Not Access")
```